# Python version mismatch, but there's just the one app

Tags: python, macos

I have a C/C++ application in which I define a Python module. I set up Python like this:

```
PyImport_AppendInittab("myModule", initmymodule);
Py_Initialize();

PyObject *module = PyImport_ImportModule("myModule");
```

On the ImportModule call, I get this warning:

> sys:1: RuntimeWarning: Python C API version mismatch for module myModule: This Python has API version 1012, module myModule has version 1013.

I'm building this app in Xcode, linking against the Python framework in /System/Library/Frameworks (which contains versions 2.3, 2.5 and 2.6). I always include the Python headers with `#include <Python/Python.h>`. How can my module have a different version if it's part of the same binary that does the initialization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are there any other Pythons installed in `/Library/Frameworks/`, like ones from a python.org installer?

Comment: Yes, there's one there that's version 2.4. Apparently Xcode is getting confused about which one it's using. So the question is how to straighten that out.

Comment: I went ahead and deleted the 2.4 framework. It's not really needed as far as I can tell.

Comment: Only if you want to use Python 2.4. Any Python frameworks in `/Library/Frameworks` are fair game to delete but you should not, of course, delete things in `/System/Library/Frameworks`.